# How come Mr. Braun doesn't remember Suzuha?

Tags: steins-gate

In episode 16 Suzuha goes back in time. Unlike what happens when they send a D-Mail or time-leap, this doesn't cause the divergence ratio to shift — which in turn means all lab members still remember her, since she was *just there*.

However, after that, [Mr. Braun goes to the lab to give Okabe Rintarou a letter from Suzuha](https://youtu.be/IbOPxRSR6BQ?t=833), saying:

> It's a letter from someone who once took care of me.

Does he not remember her working for him as a part-timer? That would be weird, given everyone else in the lab appears to still remember her.

Or is the name change — from Amane Suzuha to Hashida Suzu — along with the age difference enough to make him not realize they're the same person?

Answer (score 3):

As you pointed out, yes it is because of the name change. But let's look at the timeline of events after Suzuha  travels back to 1975 without changing the divergence ratio.

- 1975: Suzuha Amane (19 years old) arrives in Tokyo but suffers amnesia.
- 1978: Yugo Tennouji (aka Mr. Braun) is born.
- 1999: Suzuha Amane (43 years old) remembers the events from before the time travel. In this time she helped Yugo Tennouji (aka Mr. Braun), who was 21 years old at that time, as Hashida Suzu. Suzuha Amane/Hashida Suzu suicides.
- 2010: The 19 years old Suzuha Amane arrives in Tokyo and applies as a part-time worker at Yugo Tennouji (aka Mr. Braun) CRT store. Yugo Tennouji (aka Mr. Braun) is 32 years old in 2010.

So he only knew a 43 year-old friendly lady with the name Hashida Suzu who helped him 11 years before the events of D-Mail. It's not absurd that he doesn't connect her with a 19 year-old Suzuha Amane.

Source: [Suzuha Amane Wiki](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Suzuha_Amane), [Yugo Tennouji Wiki](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Yugo_Tennouji)

Comment: So they only met in 1999, the same year she remembered everything and committed suicide? I would have read "someone who once took care of me" as something of a more lasting relationship between the two of them, hence my confusion about him not recognizing her, even despite the name change and age difference.

Comment: it's not stated how long mr braun was with suzuha or when he startet to live with her, but the date 1999 is stated with the events i mentioned. also mr braun said, that he didn't realy beleived in time travel when sern hired him.

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that Mr. Braun does recognize Suzuha, but plays it cool.

Even if he's bad with faces and her appearance changed a lot in 20 years: Someone named Suzuha shows up riding your dead friend Suzuha's damn bike? The same bike that's still sitting in your yard because you weren't able to bring yourself to throw away in the last 10 years?

Secret agent that he is, Mr. Braun hides his surprise, plays his role and doesn't ask questions.